# Efficient computation of $\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, summation, computational-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I realize that there is probably not a closed form, but is there an efficient way to calculate the following expression?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$$

I've noticed $$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor} \left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor + \sum_{k=1,\ odd(k)}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$$

But I can't see an easy way to let the second term enter in a recursion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the initial sum see sequence [A006218 from OEIS](https://oeis.org/A006218) and the Wikipedia page about the ['Divisor summatory function'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_summatory_function).

Richard Sladkey's paper ['A Successive Approximation Algorithm for Computing the Divisor Summatory Function'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3369) proposes evolutions of the classical  :
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor=2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor} \left\lfloor \frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor^2$$
(perhaps that making this recursive...)

Some other references :

- A corresponding [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133630/divisor-summatory-function-for-squares) from Rick Sladkey at S.E.
- Another [thread]([A triangular representation for the divisor summatory function, $D(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5574/a-triangular-)
  representation-for-the-divisor-summatory-function-dx) with javascript.
- Tao and all's paper ['Deterministic methods to find primes'](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.3956)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Raymond's neat formula, I found the following less neat version.
It is based on the observation that after around $\sqrt n$ terms, we start seeing a lot of repeated values. By looking at how many solutions there are to $\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\rfloor=a$ we can get an expression like:

$$\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{\left\lfloor\sqrt n\right\rfloor-1}\right\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor}_\text{Direct calculation of sparse values} + \underbrace{\sum_{a=1}^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}a\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{a}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{a+1}\right\rfloor\right)}_\text{Grouped calculation of dense values}$$

This is useful if you need to sum something more complex like $\sum_{k=1}^nk^m\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k}\right\rfloor$

Answer (score -3):

Your formula is wrong

With $n = 7$ we have

result $= ⌊7/1⌋ + ⌊7/2⌋ + ⌊7/3⌋ + ⌊7/4⌋ + ⌊7/5⌋ + ⌊7/6⌋ + ⌊7/7⌋$

$ = 7 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 16$

but your function give

result $= ⌊$(⌊7/1⌋ + ⌊7/2⌋ + ⌊7/3⌋)$/ 2⌋$ + (⌊7/1⌋ + ⌊7/3⌋ + ⌊7/5⌋ + ⌊7/7⌋) $= 6 + 11 = 17$