# Summation with Floor Function

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Is there a particular formula for

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 \left \lfloor \frac{x}{i^2} \right \rfloor $$ where $x$ is an integer such that $n^2\leq x\leq (n+1)^2$. I have been trying for a long time and still not have reached to any conclusion.

Comment: I highly doubt a simple formula exists. Look at [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384520/efficient-computation-of-sum-k-1n-lfloor-fracnk-rfloor) similar [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414065/closed-form-of-sum-limits-i-1n-left-lfloor-fracni-right-rfloor2?noredirect=1&lq=1) to see the difficulty of seemingly innocuous sums like this. Would an asymptotic formula be good enough for your purposes?